# select first X rows and delete the rest

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, limit

I have a regular process that creates a few thousand rows in a DB, like a daily cron task. I don't know how many visits we'll have.

For some metrics purposes I want to trim to just keep the first 5000 rows and delete the rest.

Without going through an intermediate table is there a way to just delete the extra rows? I don't know AOT how many there will be.

Otherwise I was going to do two queries eg
`update` a field with a `limit 5000` then delete the unmarked ones.

Or `DELETE where $condition limit (7000-5000)` but I would still need to do a first query to calculate the number of rows.

Is there a way to do it with some type of nested single query?

```
DELETE where $todays_date 
limit (
  select count(*) where $todays_date - 5000
)
```

- I need to prep the data for an external metrics system that won't allow LIMIT queries - it will just slurp in all the matching data for comparisons over different times.
- I can't delete the *whole* table as there are many other variations of the single condition in it (eg historical data ranges). I just need to delete

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- Your table as a unique identifier on each row (which I'll call `id`)
- And your table has a way of specifying "first"

Then you can use a `where` clause.  Say you want the 5000 lowest ordered ids:

```
delete from `table` t
    where t.id not in (select t2.id from `table` t2 order by t2.id limit 5000);
```

Comment: so I assume t is the table, what is `t2` here? I don't quite get the `from t t2` syntax

Comment: I cannot just use the same `tname` in the `where tabname.id not in (select tabname.id from tabname order by tabname.id limit 5000)`

Comment: well, that just nuked everything else in the table... \o/

Comment: so i can't easily do the condition inside as that will not match any of the other data in the table `delete FROM chat_stats

    where session not in (
        select t2.session 
        from chat_stats t2 
        where set_name='ffw_0630'
        order by t2.session limit 5000
    );`

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace table your_table as 
select * from your_table limit 5000
```

Comment: thanks but, I don't want to replace the whole table, just truncate the num of rows that meet a set `$condition`

Comment: i was confused by your statement - `and delete the rest`. so if you need just select - just use `select * from your_table where your_conditions limit 5000`

Comment: I cannot do that as the data is also selected by some external dumb metrics dashboard without a limit query.

Comment: I think you should update your question with more details - other wise it is quite not clear what exactly your use case!

Comment: see my first comment! just use simple select part ...